# Navigating between views using Toolbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, uitoolbar

In my app, I require the main page to contain a toolbar at the top of the view. This view has a tableView. So my application cannot have a NavigationController.

**Problem**

When I want to navigate to the other view on click of the tableview cell then I am using the "pushViewController:animated:" method but it doesnt seem to work.

I checked the connections in IB. They are fine.

How can I navigate between pages without navigation controller??

I do not want to use the modal view for other views.

Please Suggest some Method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an instance of UINavigationController without having it displayed and using it for navigation.

Load your first view controller with your instance of UINavigationController in your appDelegate implementation.

Like:

```
FirstScreenController *fsc=[[FirstScreenController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FirstScreenController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navigation=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:fsc];
navigation.navigationBar.hidden=YES;
[window addSubview:navigation.view];
```

Here FirstScreenController can be your view controller having the toolbar and tableview.If you want to display another view on any click of the tableviewcell, call it this way.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondviewcontroller animated:NO];
```

Comment: Don't forget to release `fsc`.